# Select JSON unformatted code and pretty print formatted JSON into DIV

Tags: javascript, json, format, pretty-print

I have a function that takes in a selection text which is an unformatted JSON code and im trying to use stringify method to format the JSON code into a (pretty) view. This is the code:

```
 function prettyPrintJSON(selectionInfo) {
  const unformattedJSON = selectionInfo.selectionText
  const formattedJSON = JSON.stringify(unformattedJSON, null, '\t')
}
```

This is the unformatted JSON code:

```
{"colors":[{"color":"black","category":"hue","type":"primary","code":{"rgba":[255,255,255,1],"hex":"#000"}},{"color":"white","category":"value","code":{"rgba":[0,0,0,1],"hex":"#FFF"}},{"color":"red","category":"hue","type":"primary","code":{"rgba":[255,0,0,1],"hex":"#FF0"}},{"color":"blue","category":"hue","type":"primary","code":{"rgba":[0,0,255,1],"hex":"#00F"}},{"color":"yellow","category":"hue","type":"primary","code":{"rgba":[255,255,0,1],"hex":"#FF0"}},{"color":"green","category":"hue","type":"secondary","code":{"rgba":[0,255,0,1],"hex":"#0F0"}}]}
```

And this how it looks in the table:
[image]

As you can see it's not formatted. Also, im using this on a google chrome extension and using vue.js as framework to build a table to output different types of data in the same table. Any ideas what I'm missing? Thank you

Comment: Remove `null and "\t"` from `JSON.stringify(unformattedJSON, null, '\t')`, so that it's just `JSON.stringify(unformattedJSON)`

Comment: I just tried this and the output still looks the same.

Comment: I figured out, i was missing the <pre> tag for the display.

Comment: I was literally just going to tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

Turn that `\t` into a digit to represent how many indent spaces you want

```js
let json = {"colors":[{"color":"black","category":"hue","type":"primary","code":{"rgba":[255,255,255,1],"hex":"#000"}},{"color":"white","category":"value","code":{"rgba":[0,0,0,1],"hex":"#FFF"}},{"color":"red","category":"hue","type":"primary","code":{"rgba":[255,0,0,1],"hex":"#FF0"}},{"color":"blue","category":"hue","type":"primary","code":{"rgba":[0,0,255,1],"hex":"#00F"}},{"color":"yellow","category":"hue","type":"primary","code":{"rgba":[255,255,0,1],"hex":"#FF0"}},{"color":"green","category":"hue","type":"secondary","code":{"rgba":[0,255,0,1],"hex":"#0F0"}}]} 
 ;
 
console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)); // spacing level = 2);
```